# Url parse regulare expression

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following code:

```
preg_match('%^(\w+)(/(\w+))?$%', $pathInfo, $matches);
```

to parse a url string.
Can somebody can explain me what this expression parse?
Because it works great with /example, but with /example one, or /example-one doens't work anymore for $matches[1]. Thanks!

Comment: See also http://regular-expressions.info/ for the syntax tutorial, or strfriend.com for a visual explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because `\w` matches alphanumeric characters plus an underscore. It will not match a hyphen and a space.

Short solution: add them to a character class, turn `\w` into `[\w -]`.

Long solution: use `normal* (special normal*)*` to minimize the amount of backtracking, with `normal` being `\w` and `special` being `[- ]`:

```
%^(\w+(?:[- ]\w+)*)(/(?:\w+(?:[- ]\w+)*))?$%
```